# HTML - Specifying size of rows and columns?

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I'm trying to set each data cell to a certain size.  While most of the data cells are the same size, cells: d, h, l and p are smaller than the rest even though I specified their widths to be 30%.  Am I supposed to specify each cell like I've done?  Is there an easier way?  And why are those specific cells smaller than the rest when I designated them the same width?

At this point in time, I'm just trying to get each cell to be a consistent size.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Fruit Production.</title>
   </head>


 <table border = "2">
  <tr>
     <td width = "30%">a</td>
     <td width = "30%">b</td>
     <td width = "30%">c</td>

     <td width = "30%">d</td>

  </tr>


  <tr> 
     <td width = "30%">e</td>
     <td width = "30%">f</td>
     <td width = "30%">g</td>

     <td width = "30%">h</td>



   </tr>
     <td width = "30%">i</td>
     <td width = "30%">j</td>
     <td width = "30%">k</td>

     <td width = "30%">l</td>






   <tr>
     <td width = "30%">m</td>
     <td width = "30%">n</td>
     <td width = "30%">o</td>

     <td width = "30%">p</td>



    </tr>






  </table> 

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mary.  That seems like a nifty trick.  I've been unsuccessful applying that method tho.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It seems that you want the total width of the table to be bigger than it is (120% of itself). It is thus unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the widths of the TDs inside a TR should be 100%.

Since that percentage is a percentage of the TR.

So the total right now is 120%, you can try changing the 30% to 25% and they'll all be the same size.

If you want the TR to itself to be bigger, specify the width of the TR also.

Comment: When I change the td to 25%, they are all the same size, but too small for my needs.  I need them to be bigger.  How could I go about making them all bigger without running into going over 100%?

Comment: @user3577397 You can try make your `TR` wider.

Comment: Yeah make the TR bigger, so the '100%' is wider, hence making the '25%' wider too